# Django-admin: Changing field values in change form before rendering

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin, django-models

There's a link in custom view that points to Django-admin change form of specific model instance. The goal is to change values of some form fields before form rendering, like it's possible to prepopulate fields in add form by adding parameters (ModelFieldName=value) to add form URL. How to change values in change form fields before rendering? Maybe, I must create my ModelForm, change fields values in it and assign to form variable of ModelAdmin? If so, how to change values of ModelForm fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured that ModelAdmin.add_view uses request.GET to set initial in django/contrib/admin/options.py line 900.

So to prepopulate the "name" field of the someapp.somemodel add form with 'bar', just open: /admin/someapp/somemodel/add/?name=bar

Now if you want a similar behaviour in the change form, override get_object method as such:

```
def get_object(self, request, object_id):
    obj = super(YourModelAdmin, self).get_object(request, object_id)
    for key, value in request.GET.items():
        setattr(obj, key, value)
    return obj
```

Now open /admin/someapp/somemodel/1/?name=bar and the field "name" will have value "bar" in the form.

This is tested **hack**.

Comment: But [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values) i see: These values are only displayed for unbound forms. My change form is bound.

Comment: You say "prepopulate fields in add form". Add form is not bound that's for sure.

Comment: "like it's possible ... in add form"
Nevertheless, thank you for your effort!

Comment: I see, the little inconsistency between FormView (where get_form() returns a form instance, get_form_class() returns a form class) and ModelAdmin.get_form which returns a form class. So the only solution here looks like overriding add_view() and re-doing request.POST.

Comment: Why to override add_view(), if I need data changing?

Comment: I don't understand what you want after all. Put some effort in making your question clear, put code examples, expected behaviors etc ...

Comment: I want to change values in fields of change form before rendering.

Comment: Yes, prepopulating in add form works fine! But I need the same for change form.

Comment: I see, i think we have the solution now !

Comment: Wow! It works! :) Thank you very much!
It've required more complex setattr construction, such as
setattr(obj, 'photographer', Photographer.objects.get(pk= int(request.GET['photographer']))) But now it's not critical.